# SciChart - How to display only certain label on a numeric axis?

Tags: label, axis, scichart

I have a chart with numeric axis and would like to display only certain numbers, i.e.,
the range is 0-500 and I would like to have major ticks with labels on 0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250 and 500.

Could you provide some guidelines how to achive it? Custom LabelProvider?

Comment: Is this scichart WPF, javascript, ios or android? Can you share some code that you've tried so far and an image/diagram of the desired output? Edit the question with the new details and will check back shortly.